# Two requests per ListItem to load image in RecyclerView

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, retrofit, spotify

I have a RecyclerView.Adapter with Artists. I use the artist's name to look it up on Spotify (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/) to get a thumbnail for each artist. Then I use the url of the thumbnail to fetch the image. At the moment I'm using Glide for ImageLoading and Caching.

The problem is that when I'm scrolling fast it's laggy and after a while it crashes with an OutOfMemoryError:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
                                                             at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
                                                             at okhttp3.Dispatcher.enqueue(Dispatcher.java:112)
                                                             at okhttp3.RealCall.enqueue(RealCall.java:78)
                                                             at okhttp3.RealCall.enqueue(RealCall.java:70)
                                                             at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:101)
                                                             at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.enqueue(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:60)
                                                             at at.audiocracy.adapter.ArtistAdapter.fetchArtistImage(ArtistAdapter.java:79)
```

My optimizations so far:

- Save the Spotify-Url for each artist in the ArrayList to prevent looking up an artist a 2nd time
- add the retrofit-call to each ViewHolder and cancel the request if the ViewHolder is recycled

My questions are - how do I prevent it from crashing? How do I optimize my Adapter in a way that scrolling is fluent? How do I cache those thumbnails best?

Comment: You using a library to load images?

Comment: Yes, Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 1):

Well you are getting an out of memory exception due to too much memory usage. A non-exhaustive list for what you can do is the following:

- Do not load the full image into memory.
- Reuse bitmaps if possible.
- Make sure bitmaps are not being unnecessarily held in memory (easy to accidentally do in a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`).
- Use some form of [caching](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).
- Do image processing work off the main thread.

This can be seen in [android docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html). You can come up with an nice solution if you spent quite some time in it. But with recycler view there are some edge cases that you may encounter.

Ultimately it makes more sense for you to use a library to load images efficiently so you don't worry about this. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) are the most popular. Don't reinvent the wheel. Those libraries have a lot of work in them. Make use of this.

Edit:

It seems you are using a library, which is awesome. I notice they have a section [Loading and Caching on Background Threads](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). Make use of that if you aren't already. Just play with the configuration and make sure you aren't doing unnecessary work.